# offseX values are different in different browsers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, d3.js

I have a slider. On clicking below slider axis, `onClickHorizontal` function is called but the value of `d3.event.offsetX` is different in Chrome(50.0.2661.102) and Firefox(42.0) due to which slider position is different even though I click at the same position of slider in both the browsers

https://github.com/MasterMaps/d3-slider/blob/master/d3.slider.js#L216

```
function onClickHorizontal() {
    if (toType(value) != "array") {
        var pos = Math.max(0, Math.min(sliderLength, d3.event.offsetX || d3.event.layerX));
        moveHandle(scale.invert ?
                    stepValue(scale.invert(pos / sliderLength)) :
                    nearestTick(pos / sliderLength));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using Opera 38 and Firefox 43 both of them give me same values. So, maybe Chrome is the problem